# Insert key and value from one Javascript object into another Javascript object

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following two Javascript objects:

```
let platformModules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Module One',
    icon: 'icon-01',
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Module Two',
    icon: 'icon-02',
    deleted: false
  }
]
```

and

```
let companyModules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    companyId: 4,
    name: 'Our second module',
    enabled: true,
    position: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    companyId: 4,
    name: 'Our first module',
    enabled: true,
    position: 1
  }
]
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to take the `icon` key (and it's value) 
 from `platformModules` and insert it into a new object based on `companyModules`, like the example below:

```
let displayModules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    companyId: 4,
    name: 'Our second module',
    enabled: true,
    position: 2,
    icon: 'icon-01'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    companyId: 4,
    name: 'Our first module',
    enabled: true,
    position: 1,
    icon: 'icon-01'
  }
]
```

I have tried the follow, but it is not working:

```
function findAndMerge (source, target, findKey) {
  for (var key in source) {
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(key) && source[key] === findKey) {
      target[key] = source[key]
    }
  }
}
let displayModules = findAndMerge(platformModules, companyModules, icon)
```

Any help, pointers would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: `source[key] === findKey` - if you're passing in the `key` - shouldn't it be `key === findKey` - also what is not working? What is `icon` in your case when you call this method?

Comment: `platformModules.map((object, index) => ({
   ...object,
   ...companyModules[index]
}))`. Of course, you will need to ensure that the elements at the indexes have the same id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Array's `map()` to loop through the base array (`companyModules`) and then assign the object from `platformModules` by using `Object.assign()`. Try the following:

```js
let platformModules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Module One',
    icon: 'icon-01',
    deleted: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Module Two',
    icon: 'icon-02',
    deleted: false
  }
]

let companyModules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    companyId: 4,
    name: 'Our second module',
    enabled: true,
    position: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    companyId: 4,
    name: 'Our first module',
    enabled: true,
    position: 1
  }
]

var displayModules = companyModules.map(function(item, i){
  return Object.assign({'icon':platformModules[i].icon},item);
});
console.log(displayModules);
```

Comment: Yup, thanks, that did the job nicely. Much appreciated.

Comment: @NeilMerton, you are most welcome.